# Programmatically connect my SSISDB packages to environmental reference

Tags: ssis

I am using project deployment. I have several project parameters. My packages only use project-level parameters, and no package-level ones. I have programatically deployed my project and set an environmental reference:

[image: SSISDB config]

I call each package from a SQL Agent job. I am unable to link my environment variables to the package when it runs. I have successfully linked the *project* to the environment:

[image: Project param config]

[image: project env ref]

But now when I run my agent job, it fails. When I look at the SSISDB reports, it says it "created execution", but shows no variables.

Do I actually have to explicitly link every variable in each package to the environment variable? Why even bother to group them by environment?

I have created my environmental references like this (sql cmd):

```
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_environment_reference] @environment_name='$(ChooseEnvironment)', @reference_id=@reference_id OUTPUT, @project_name='$(ProjectName)', @folder_name='$(folderName)', @reference_type=R
EXEC SSISDB.catalog.set_object_parameter_value @parameter_name=N'EmailFrom', @parameter_value='EmailFrom', @project_name=$(ProjectName), @object_type=20, @folder_name=$(FolderName), @value_type=N'R'
```

---

Additional info: I have created a sql agent job that calls each package with a job step like this:

```
set @cmd = N'/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\CHAT\SSISPackages\Chat_Load_RMS_InputFiles.dtsx\"" /SERVER "\"' + @TargetDBServer + '\"" /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E'

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, 
@step_name=N'PACKAGE: Chat_Load_RMS_InputFiles.dtsx', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=3, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        @command=@cmd,
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
```

Do I need to add a reference id to my SSIS @cmd variable? Also, if I address this in the job, can I remove my code above to set each project-level variable to an environment, or do I still need that? It seems like for cleanliness, I should just be able to say: this project uses this environment. Done. Otherwise, it's almost like using package-level variables and all the tinkering those require.

---

Comment: You have to create an environment variable for each of your project parameters.   High level, create environment,  create variables within that environment, add reference of that environment to your deployed project, then for each of the parameters change them to "Use environment variable" and select which environment variable you're wanting to use.

Comment: Then when creating the agent job you tell it what environment to use.  In the job step, under configuration there's a checkbox and drop down.  Which equates to "/ENVREFERENCE ##" via the command line.  ## being the [reference_id] value from [internal].[environment_references] in the SSISDB.

Comment: Thank you, @TimMylott. If you break this second comment out, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: and you don't have to use environments.  There can be some overhead with configurations, etc.  We use them because we don't really look at "environments" as in DEV, UAT or PROD, but rather groupings of configurations and in some situations we have multiple environments.  So we can use the same package in different jobs, but each one get's it's own specific values/configuration by way of different environments.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a package as an "direct" SSIS step in SQL Agent step, you have to select the environment in the package configuration tab on the step configuration dialog.

If you running it using TSQL script you need to provide a reference id when calling `catalog.create_execution`:

```
    DECLARE
        @reference_id bigint,
        @FullPackageName NVARCHAR(100);

    SELECT @reference_id = reference_id
        FROM  [$(SSISDB)].catalog.environment_references er
            INNER JOIN [$(SSISDB)].catalog.projects AS p 
                ON p.project_id = er.project_id
            INNER JOIN [$(SSISDB)].catalog.folders AS f
                ON f.folder_id = p.folder_id
    WHERE  er.environment_folder_name IS NULL
        AND er.environment_name = @EnvironmentName
        AND p.name              = @ProjectName
        AND f.name              = @FolderName;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE
            @msg NVARCHAR(100);

        SET @msg = N'Could not find a reference for a local (.) ''' + @EnvironmentName + N''' environment.';
        THROW 50000, @msg, 1;
    END;

    SET @FullPackageName = @PackageName + N'.dtsx';

    EXEC [$(SSISDB)].catalog.create_execution
        @package_name = @FullPackageName,
        @execution_id = @execution_id OUTPUT,
        @folder_name = @FolderName,
        @project_name = @ProjectName,
        @use32bitruntime = False,
        @reference_id = @reference_id;
```

Comment: Hm, okay. I've edited my question above to flesh out how I am calling it via the SQL Agent job.

Comment: Do you have your environment checkbox and name selected in the SQL Agent dialog? Could you script your job and check if the "/ENVREFERENCE {int here}" is set in the job step command?

Comment: I checked that box in the Job Step config, rescripted it, and now I see a parameter /ENVREFERENCE. I so suspect that's it.

This is going to be a lot less elegant than I'd hoped, but that's life, I guess. Thanks!